# How can we turn radio button checked when we type its input

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

As you see below, I have a radio button group that has three options. The last one is text input. Is there any way to make the last one checked when I type something  in its text box?

```
<input type='radio' name='result' value="0"/><label for="0">False</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="1"/><label for="1">True</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="2"/><label for="2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your result" name="result_answ"></label>
```

Comment: i wrote my codes but i couldn't see it here, please wait i will share the codes

Comment: Don't include large amounts of code in a comment, it's unreadable, I have made a edit suggestion to your question where your code will be included :) you had simply forgotten to indent it propperly

Comment: is there any way to edit my question, i want to write my codes in the my question

Comment: If there is more code than already included then press the edit button just below the question's tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have jQuery loaded use this:

```
<input type='radio' name='result' value="0"/><label for="0">False</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="1"/><label for="1">True</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="2"/><label for="2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your result" onkeyup="jQuery(this).parent().prev().prop('checked', true)" name="result_answ"></label>
```

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/9q1j36cj/

**EDIT:**
Here is non-jQuery version:

```
<input type='radio' name='result' value="0"/><label for="0">False</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="1"/><label for="1">True</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="2"/><label for="2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your result" onkeyup="this.parentNode.previousSibling.checked = true" name="result_answ"></label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9q1j36cj/1/

Comment: Try the new version - it does not need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```js
onload = function(){

document.getElementsByName('result_answ')[0].onkeyup = function(){
  if(this.value!==''){
    document.getElementsByName('result')[2].setAttribute('checked', true);
  }else{
    document.getElementsByName('result')[2].removeAttribute('checked')
  }
}

}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='result' value="0"/><label for="0">False</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="1"/><label for="1">True</label><br/>
<input type='radio' name='result' value="2"/><label for="2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your result" name="result_answ"></label>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i already tried vakata's answer and i it worked for me...

Comment: Vakata's answer would have shortfall. if user removes text in input then the radio button should be unchecked isnt it?

Comment: in vakata's, when i remove text in input the radio button stays checked. But for my site it does the job and it's short solution. Thank you again

Comment: ohh..okk.. if thats your requirement then yeah its short and fast solution. I am gonna give +1 to that answer.

Comment: i have just tried your post, yeah it's better solution, i will keep it in my head, i'm sure i'm gonna need it.